# Swift table only show 1 column

Tags: uitableview, swiftui

I am new to Xcode, and facing some issues while creating a table view.

Problem: In iOS 14 Plus simulator, only 1 columns is shown - "Category" and without header. The entire column "Total" is completely missing. However, when I switch the simulation to ipad, everything is working fine. Really appreciate if someone could help to resolve this issue.

```
struct OverallObj: Identifiable {
    var category: String
    var total: Int
    var id: String {
        category
    }

    static var summary: [OverallObj] {
        [
            OverallObj(category: "1st", total: 1000),
            OverallObj(category: "2nd", total: 1000)
        ]
    }
}

var body: some View {
    Table(overallView) {
        TableColumn("Category", value: \.category)
        TableColumn("Total") { overallObj in
            Text("\(overallObj.total)")
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the table to show 2 columns - "Category" and "Total" with headers

Comment: What is `overallView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your specific case is caused by the [compact horizontal size](https://medium.design/regular-and-compact-ios-display-size-breakdown-for-designers-d3ff3044e06e) on iOS.
From the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Table):

> MacOS and iPadOS support SwiftUI tables. On iOS, and in other
> situations with a compact horizontal size class, tables don’t show
> headers and collapse all columns after the first. If you present a
> table on iOS, you can customize the table’s appearance by implementing
> compact-specific logic in the first column.

You can implement compact-specific logic in the first column of a table in SwiftUI by using the environment modifier and checking the `sizeCategory` environment value.
If the size category is compact, you can return a compact version of the view for the first column with all the data you need to display, otherwise return the normal version of the view.

Here is an example:

```
 @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeCategory

 var body: some View {
     Table(overallView) {
         TableColumn("Category") { item in
             if (sizeCategory == .compact) {
                 // Return compact version of the view
                 Text("Compact")
             } else {
                 // Return normal version of the view
                 Text("Normal")
             }
         }
         TableColumn("Total") { overallObj in
         Text("\(overallObj.total)")
     }
 }
```

Comment: thanks! alternatively @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var sizeCategory also works

Comment: So there is no way to get multiple columns in general? One responds to `sizeCategory` and gets what `Table()` produces on iOS?  This is, I took this above example, replaced `Text("Compact")` with `Text("C")` and got one column w/o any headings.  Are you saying I should see multiple columns??

Comment: And, in my test with `Text("C")`, landscape mode showed a single column of "C" w/o headings too.

Answer (score 1):

Using tables on different platforms
macOS and iPadOS support SwiftUI tables. On iOS, and in other situations with a compact horizontal size class, tables don’t show headers and collapse all columns after the first. If you present a table on iOS, you can customize the table’s appearance by implementing compact-specific logic in the first column.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Table